# Troubles with recovering and echo or printing $_GET

Tags: php, get, codeigniter-4

So I'm having troubles with $_GET.

I cant seem to recover and echo or print the $_POST from my form in a different .php file (im using codeigniter4 btw). Can someone help? thank you

This is the code for "echoing" the $_GET in a different file
(this is all inside an if statement with isset($_GET['variable'])

```
  $name = $_GET["name"];
  $email = $_GET["email"];
  $suggestions = $_GET["suggestions"];

  $output = "Name: " . $name . "\n";
  $output .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";
  $output .= "Suggestions: " . $suggestions;

  echo $output;
```

This is my controller code

```
$data = 
[
    'name',
    'email',
    'suggestions',
    'accept_terms'
];
       
    if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post')
    {
        $rules = 
        [
            'name'          => 'required',
            'email'         => 'required|valid_email',
            'suggestions'   => 'required',
            'accept_terms'  => 'required',         
        ];
        
        if($this->validate($rules))
        {
            return redirect()->to('/Savefeedback');
        }else 
        {
            $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
        }
        
    }   
    
    return view('Signup',$data);
```

Comment: Please do share your code not the screen shot.

Comment: oops sorry let me edit it

Comment: You are POST ing data but trying to GET it? Or am I wrong? Can you try to change $_GET to $_POST

Comment: yes sir, correct. let me try

Comment: yeah so its still not working. Tried replacing the $_GET's to $_POST's and vice versa

Comment: The first snippet is from your view?

Comment: yes, it is. I have 2 view that are connected to each other. 1st view is the index, 2nd view is when the submit button is clicked, the 2nd view is where I'm trying to echo my data from the forms from the 1st view.

Comment: first when I looked at your code your $data array does not have value. What is your output when you submit your form? is it like Name: null ?

Comment: the $data is for the validation rules i have. 

when i simply 'echo' my $_POST in the 1st view it works fine. no issues with the recovered data from the form. but when i try to 'echo' it from the second form it does not show at all. therefore, there is no output.

Comment: Are you setting these data to next form? For the 2. time it clears all the data and you got nothing. Set first data to your second data.

Comment: which data are you referring to? from the validation rule? or the forms?